# Algorithms for matching video feed from mobile camera with the map of the venue

Tags: algorithm, mobile, video-processing

You have the map of the building (and perhaps pictures). You walk around in the building with a mobile and record a 1s-3s video.

What algorithms would you recommend to use to find out in which place in the building you currently are? (the goal is to match the video feed with the map of the building in a mobile app, so the computational resources need to be taken into consideration)

I am writing code in Swift and Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put something like this into the building: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARTag
or QR codes encoding the location.